# Connection timeout on seemingly random clients

Tags: apache2, connection, ufw, timeout

I am facing issues hosting an apache2 server on Ubuntu 18.04. Some of my friends get a connection timeout when trying to access it, I myself cannot reproduce this behavior. It doesn't matter if I'm in the same LAN as the server or if I'm using mobile networks to access the web server. also, it doesn't matter if I'm trying to connect via the DynDNS or the external IP. the same way for my friends trying to reach the web server.
What I realized is that I cannot ping my server regardless of ICMP being active or not. turning off UFW doesn't change anything regarding that problem. I cannot think of a logical reason for this behavior and thus want to ask the community if anyone has an idea about if there might be a connection between those two problems and how to debug or solve the problem of getting seemingly random connection timeouts on different clients since apache access.log doesn't display anything on ongoing connections, neither does error.log.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should ask on the #ubuntu-server help on freenode, but for me it's network issue, it can be the router, as I guess. You must check the router and the Dynamic DNS service, maybe the IP change to fast that can also cause it. Anyway this question should be on server section not askubuntu :)